# How to using bootstrap in laravel dompdf?

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, laravel, pdf, laravel-5.3

My controller is like this :

```
public function listdata()
{
    $pdf=PDF::loadView('print_tests.pdf');
    $pdf->setPaper('legal', 'landscape');
    return $pdf->stream('test_pdf.pdf');
}
```

My view (pdf.blade.php) is like this :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <title>Cetak Laplakgar</title>
        <body>
            <div class="container">
              <div class="jumbotron">
                <h1>My First Bootstrap Page</h1>
                <p>Resize this responsive page to see the effect!</p>
              </div>
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-4">
                  <h3>Column 1</h3>
                  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit...</p>
                  <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris...</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-4">
                  <h3>Column 2</h3>
                  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit...</p>
                  <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris...</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-4">
                  <h3>Column 3</h3>
                  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit...</p>
                  <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris...</p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
        </body>
    </head>
</html>
```

When I don't using bootstrap, It's working

When I using bootstrap, It's not working. There is exist error like this :

```
ErrorException in BinaryStream.php line 254: strftime() expects parameter 2 to be integer, float given
```

Is there any people who can help me?

Comment: https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/issues/1231

Answer (score -1):

It seems, it's a bug of the package... https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/issues/631